# Show content dependent on user choice

Tags: 8

For a car selling website, there is need that the user choose his car and depending on his choice, another list should appear with the available models.

I search to do this on a conditional system, but also a list with hidden submenus would be acceptable.

Comment: Waiting for conditional fields module to be stable, you can easily do it with JavaScript. See [\[conditional_fields\] Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2609628).

Comment: The development snapshot for the [Conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module works on Drupal 8.5.x and with PHP 7.

Answer (score 4):

If you want  when user select a Car and then according to select car another select list showed with that car model I can suggest you use [simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs)  module ( I know it hasn't stable version yet),

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy
>   fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies
>   hierarchy. The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed
>   filter.
>
> This module has been inspired by Hierarchical select but is much
>   simpler (hence the name ;) ).

Also [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) is very good module to achieve field show and hide based on another field but it is not suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks I will try you suggestion, conditional fields indeed, does not work for D8

Comment: @Belba you're welcome, it seems you don't have any solution expect your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

It is working with simple hiarchical select module. Because of the long complex lists difficult to handle in Taxonomy, I also work with the Taxonomy Manager module :
https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager
It show some errors, but it works fine and once the work is done, you can uninstall it for your production website.

Answer (score 0):

I found the original title of your question quite misleading. Conditional fields is actually the wrong direction. Go for Views. Check out the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views).

---

#### Views

Let's say you have a content type "Car" and it has a lot of fields. Now first create a View  to list all "Car" nodes, sort them by whatever you want, display them however you want.

Next add *filters* to your view ([docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-filter-to-a-view)) and *expose* them to your visitors ([docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/expose-a-filter-to-site-visitors)). These filters can filter by any field of your "Car" node type. Maybe a brand filter, and a max. speed filter, and a color filter. As soon as these filters get applied (with an "Apply" button or via auto-submit) the view then only lists all "Cars" that matches the given criteria.